# Change Language dropdownlist country codes etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a dropdownlist with the country codes and country names sorted alphabetically  now how do change each page to that language by the selected item in the dropdownlist im using the RegionInfo TwoLetterISORegionName object in the dropdownlist corresponding to that country is that the correct way to do it

Comment: First thing for you to do is to add some punctuation to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to persist the selected value somewhere.

1. In page_init retrieve the selected
   value and set culture for the
   current thread (or use the Culture
   and UICulture properties on the Page
   object.
2. In page_load initialise your dropdownlist.
3. In page_prerender you set the
   selected value for the dropdownlist.
4. In your eventhandler for handling
   changing values
   (selectedindex_changed or
   button_click) persist the selected
   value from the dropdownlist
   somewhere.

I have also answered you in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243309/page-wont-change-language/5297025#5297025).