# Page won't change language

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

My page won't change the language could someone have a look at my code and tell me what im doing wrong it always goes to the default language

```
public partial class ChangeLanguage : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SortedDictionary<string, string> objDic = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (CultureInfo ObjectCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        {
            RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjectCultureInfo.Name);
            if (!objDic.ContainsKey(objRegionInfo.EnglishName))
            {
                objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.EnglishName, ObjectCultureInfo.Name);
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in objDic)
        {
            ddlCountries.Items.Add(new ListItem(val.Key, val.Value));
        }

        ddlCountries.SelectedValue = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
    }

    protected void btnChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProfileCommon profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon;
        profile.Preferences.Culture = ddlCountries.SelectedValue;
    }
}
protected override void InitializeCulture()
  {
     string culture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
     this.Culture = culture;
     this.UICulture = culture;
  }
Profile:
  <properties>
    <add name="FirstName" type="String"/>
    <add name="LastName" type="String"/>
    <add name="Gender" type="String"/>
    <add name="BirthDate" type="DateTime"/>
    <add name="Occupation" type="String"/>
    <add name="WebSite" type="String"/>
    <group name="Preferences">
      <add name="Culture" type="String" defaultValue="en-NZ" allowAnonymous="true"/>
    </group>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Does the drop down show the updated language that was selected?

Comment: No it goes back to the default value in the property Culture in Profile Preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here, but the main one is that you in Page_Load do:

```
ddlCountries.SelectedValue = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon
```

Then in the eventhandler for the click event do:

```
profile.Preferences.Culture = ddlCountries.SelectedValue;
```

Unfortunately for you, the Page_Load event fires *before* your click event, and since the Page_Load event sets the selectedvalue of the dropdownlist to the value *already* stored in the Profile object, and you then save the selectedvalue of the dropdownlist (which is no longer what you selected prior to clicking your button) you essentially just ignore the selected value and continue to use the default (or former) value.

Move the code that selects the value in the dropdownlist to Page_PreRender (remove it from Page_Load), and you will be fine (example):

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string culture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
    if (ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(culture) != null)
    {
        ddlCountries.SelectedValue = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
    }
}
```